# How to interpret this Swedish military uniform(circa 1895)?

Tags: identification, uniform, sweden

We recently found a picture of my G.Grandfather Sandstrom (on the right) at approx. 20 years of age in what I believe to be a Swedish Cavalry uniform circa 1895. There is a 6 on the side of his shako which I'm guessing was his regiment?   Mostly interested in his rank & confirmation of the time period.   Experts please chime in.

At the very least, it's an interesting documentation of history -   [image]

Comment: The six is probably some sub-unit. The regiments had slightly different uniforms, apparently (no idea which this is). Also, they are, unsurprisingly, probably not officers, as the insignia would be on the collar, it seems.